# curl and getting 100 URLs in parallel

Tags: list, url, curl, xargs

cat urllist.txt | xargs -P0 -n1 curl | grep "HREF=" > out.txt

this works fine but it connects one url at the same time. how can i curl 100 urls at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using xargs, use [parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to do it. It is quite similar to xargs but instead fires up commands in parallel - hence the name...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to benchmark a url, use apache benchmark. It ships with httpd. Sample run:

```
$ ab -n 100 -c 100 "<url>"
```

What the above does is, hit the url 100 times at a (c)oncurrency of 100